# Keep the order of a factor after applying gsub on it

Tags: r

I have this vector:

```
x <- factor(c("A.B", "C.D", "U.X", "X.U", "A.A"))
```

which is then ordered:

```
x <- factor(x, levels=rev(levels(x)), ordered=T)
x
[1] A.B C.D U.X X.U A.A
Levels: X.U < U.X < C.D < A.B < A.A
```

I want to remove the "." and replace it with spaces:

```
x <- as.factor(gsub(".", " ", x, fixed=TRUE))
```

but this does not keep the factor intact:

```
x
[1] A B C D U X X U A A
Levels: A A A B C D U X X U
str(x)
Factor w/ 5 levels "A A","A B","C D",..: 2 3 4 5 1
```

How can i perform the replacement on `x` while keeping its order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to operate on the `levels` of the factor:

```
x <- factor(c("A.B", "C.D", "U.X", "X.U", "A.A"))
x <- factor(x, levels=rev(levels(x)), ordered=T)
levels(x) <- gsub(".", " ", levels(x), fixed=TRUE)
x
# [1] A B C D U X X U A A
# Levels: X U < U X < C D < A B < A A
str(x)
# Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "X U"<"U X"<"C D"<..: 4 3 2 1 5
```

This way your ordered factor is not changed except for how the factor-levels are displayed.

Answer (score 2):

After remove the "." you can reorder x as you did before

```
x <- factor(x, levels=rev(levels(x)), ordered=T)
```

Or you can do the replacement and the reorder in the same line this way

```
x <- factor(as.factor(gsub(".", " ", x, fixed=TRUE)), levels=rev(levels(as.factor(gsub(".", " ", x, fixed=TRUE)))), ordered=T)
```